# table reload.data while enter foreground

Tags: swift, uitableview, reload

good morning :)

i have a tableview controller with the following example data:

Test 1

### 20.05.2015

Test 2

### 13.07.2015

a function checking the date of the data.
if the date  == date today => font color = green

My Problem:
Yesterday, the font color of data "Test 2" was black => OK
i let the app go into background and open it today again.
the color have to be green today, but it was black, too.

after i terminate the app and open it again, the color change to green.
i have a TableLM.reloadData() in the ViewillAppear, but i dont work.
i think, i have to reload the table in the function "applicationWillEnterForeground"

but TableLM is not known in the appdelegate.swift
what can i do?

Comment: the color was wrong..mhm .. sounds like a cell reuse issue right there. are you doing cell reusing? do you set the textColor ok?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this code in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "appBecomeActive", name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil )
```

After that add this method which will reload your tableview when application will enter in foreground:

```
func appBecomeActive() {
    //reload your Tableview here
    TableLM.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: thank you very much - i works :)
but why dont work TableLM.reloadData() only in ViewWillAppear without NSNotificationCenter?

Answer (score 2):

in Swift 3.1

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourViewController.appBecomeActive), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil )
```

Answer (score 0):

AppDelegate has a function to handle this kind of situation.

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}
```

Invoke a notification in `applicationWillEnterForeground` and reload the `tableView`.